# How can I restrict user to only created limited numbers of objects

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Book
{

var $name;
   function setName($name){
          $this->name = $name;
   }
   function getName(){
         return $this->name ;
   }
}
$objectfirst = new Book;
$objectfirst->setName('English');
echo $objectfirst->getName();
$objectsecond = new Book;
$objectsecond->setName('Science');
echo $objectsecond->getName();
?>
```

How can I restrict user to only created limited numbers of objects. For above example if I will create one more object then I will throw an error.

Comment: Alternative is creating a singleton class, this makes sure that there is always 1 instance of the class never 2.

Comment: what should be the limit in your case? 2 objects?

Comment: It should not more than 2 in my case.

Comment: @Rajiv You have been given two answers below. Pick whichever answer works for you and mark it as *accepted*. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 2):

Add static counter variable to your class, add constructor and destructor to increase and decrease it. Check the value in constructor:

```
<?php
class Book
{

   var $name;
   private static $counter=0;

   function __construct()
   {
     self::$counter++;
     if(self::$counter > 2)
       throw new Exception('Limit exceeded');
   }

   function __destruct()
   {
     self::$counter--;
   }

   function setName($name){
          $this->name = $name;
   }

   function getName(){
         return $this->name ;
   }
}

$objectfirst = new Book;
$objectfirst->setName('English');
echo $objectfirst->getName();
$objectsecond = new Book;
$objectsecond->setName('Science');
echo $objectsecond->getName();

$objectthird = new Book;
$objectthird->setName('Test');
echo $objectthird->getName();
```

Script output:

```
EnglishScience
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Limit exceeded' in sandbox/scriptname.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 sandbox/scriptname.php(36): Book->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in sandbox/scriptname.php on line 12
```

Comment: mark static property `$counter` as private to avoid external modification

Comment: I would change the exception message text, but, anyway ...You got my upvote (+10)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- Keep the constructor method of the `Book` class `private`.
- Declare two class members named `$number_of_objects` and `$threshold_number_of_objects`.
- Use a separate class method, say `getInstance()` method to create new instances of `Book` class. This `getInstance()` method will create new instances of class `Book` if the number of objects already created is less than the threshold value, otherwise it'll  return error.

So your code should be like this:

```
class Book{

    private $name;
    private static $number_of_objects = 0;
    private static $threshold_number_of_objects = 2;

    // Since it's constructor method is private
    // it prevents objects from being created from 
    // outside of the class
    private function __construct(){}

    // It creates an object if the number of objects
    // already created is less than the threshold value
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$number_of_objects < self::$threshold_number_of_objects){
            ++self::$number_of_objects;
            return new Book();
        }else{
            echo "Error: Number of objects crossed the threshold value";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function setName($name){
          $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
         return $this->name ;
    }
}

//$objectfirst = new Book;  invalid
$objectfirst = Book::getInstance();
if($objectfirst){
    $objectfirst->setName('English');
    echo $objectfirst->getName() . "<br />";    
}

//$objectsecond = new Book;  invalid
$objectsecond = Book::getInstance();
if($objectsecond){
    $objectsecond->setName('Science');
    echo $objectsecond->getName() . "<br />";
}

//$objectthird = new Book;  invalid
$objectthird = Book::getInstance();
if($objectthird){
    $objectthird->setName('Engineering');
    echo $objectthird->getName() . "<br />";    
}
```

Output:

```
English
Science
Error: Number of objects crossed the threshold value
```